# Autocast from "YYYY-MM" varchar to date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have a column of type `date`, where only year and month are revelant. I would like to use shortened date format in SQL queries, like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where date_column='2019-10';
```

Of course now it results with error:

```
SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "2019-12"
```

Is there any chance to make it possible? Thank you!

---

**Edit:**

What I want to achieve is to make it automatic. I know I can cast my string to date with `to_date('2019-10','YYYY-MM')`. My question is how to make my query to look like: `SELECT * FROM my_table where date_column='2019-10'`. Without any casting and converting.

I am reading about `CREATE CAST` statement but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for here.

Comment: What you want to do doesn't make sense.  Don't mix strings and dates.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

```
where date_column >= ('2019-10' || '-01')::date and
      date_column < ('2019-10' || '-01')::date + interval '1 month'
```

This formulation allows an index on `date_column` to be used for the query, if such an index is available.

If you don't care about that, you can use `to_char()`:

```
where to_char(date_column, 'YYYY-MM') = '2019-10'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check the `YEAR` and `MONTH` separately:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_column) = 2019
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_column) = 10
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/38550)

Comment: In that case, you'd need to store the `date` value as a string with the format you want to search on.  Or possibly store it as a `YEAR TO MONTH INTERVAL` data type, if possible.

Comment: This isn't good because it won't use an index on the column, if it exists. And regardless of index, executing 2 functions per row? Slow. Better to change the format of the '2019-10' value to the same type as the column to allow a native comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A great option most people forget is to have the column remain a `character(7)`, and insert it as you did now. String comparisons using `= < <= > >=` will all work properly, so long as you stick to the ISO-8601 format, as is the example you gave, that is `YYYY-MM`. You don't really need to use a date format.

This however assumes your checking of the validity is done in the application, which would be the best way to avoid timezone problems that you'd run into with the simpler solution of checking against `current_date` in the database. That's an early warning for you, since you wouldn't know you have a timezone problem until customers complain that their payment wasn't processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    my_table 
WHERE
    DATE_PART('YEAR',CURRENT_DATE)='2019' AND
    DATE_PART('MONTH',CURRENT_DATE)='10';
```